# Add event to another event? c#

Tags: c#, events

```
class a 
{
    public event Action foo;
    var zzz = new b();
    foo += zzz.bar;
}

class b 
{
    public Action bar;
}
```

The above (pseudo) code works and compiles fine.

However, if i change `bar` to `public event Action bar` I cant then add it to `foo`. 
Basically I would like to add one event to another. Im aware this could sound abit ridiculous.

Comment: I don't think your code can be compiled.

Comment: He actually wrote, that it is pseudo code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you want to achieve is something like this (I guess):

1. `foo` event is triggered:
   call all `foo` subscribed event handlers plus all `bar` subscribed event handlers.
2. `bar` is triggered:
   call all `bar` subscribed event handlers plus all `foo` subscribed event handlers.

---

```
class a 
{
    public event Action foo;
    b zzz = new b();
    public a()
    {
        // this allow you to achieve point (1)
        foo += zzz.FireBarEvent;
        // this allow you to achieve point (2)
        zzz.bar += OnBar;
    }
    void OnBar()
    {
        FireFooEvent();
    }
    void FireFooEvent()
    {
        if(foo != null)
            foo();
    }
}

class b 
{
    public event Action bar;
    public void FireBarEvent()
    {
       if(bar != null)
           bar();
    }
}
```

**CAVEAT:**

this code (if (1) and (2) options are both enabled) cause an infinite numbers of calls i.e.:

```
foo --> bar --> foo --> bar ...
```

that has to be managed properly.

Comment: An intermediary method, I think for readability this approach the best.

Comment: @maxp: thx, just have a look at the caveat for completeness ;)

Answer (score 3):

IIRC you can't invoke events from another class directly.

```
class A {
    public A() {
        b = new B(this);
    }

    private B b;
    public event Action Foo;
}

class B {
    public B(A a) {
        a.Foo += InvokeBar;
    }

    public event Action Bar;

    private void InvokeBar() {
        if (Bar != null)
            Bar();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, quite annoying. You can't even invoke them from derived classes either. You can invoke delegates though, so its almost worth using a generic list of delegates instead of an event.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>If bar is a public event, then you use a lambda to invoke the bar event:</strike>

```
foo += () => zzz.bar();
```

This is not the exact syntax, researching...

This is not possible, because you cannot call the bar event from outside the class it is defined in.

You should use a solution like this;

```
class b {
    public Action bar;
    public void InvokeBar() {
       if (bar != null) bar();
    }
}
```

Then you can use InvokeBar as a target for your event.